# QuickSort giving incorrect sorting order

Tags: java, quicksort

I am new to Java and I am trying to implement QuickSort.
Here is my script below.

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a[] ={5,6,7,4,1,3};
        QuickSort qs = new QuickSort();
        qs.quickSort(a,0,a.length-1);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }

    }
    public void quickSort(int[] a,int left, int length) {

        if(left >= length) return;
        int index = partition(a,left,length);
        if(left < index) {
            quickSort(a,left,index-1);
        }
        else {
            quickSort(a,index,length);
        }
    }

    private  int partition(int[] a,int l, int length) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int left = l;
        int right = length;
        int pivot = a[(left+right)/2];
        while(left <= right) {
            while(left < length && a[left] < pivot) {
                left++;
            } 
            while(right >= 0 && a[right] > pivot) {
                right--;
            }
            if(left <= right) {
                int temp = a[left];
                a[left]=a[right];
                a[right]=temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }

}
```

When , I print the solution I get the following order-

```
[1,3,6,4,5,7]
```

I am unable to figure out the error, can anyone please help me fix this problem.

Comment: why don't you try using a debugger and go line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change this

```
if(left < index) {
    quickSort(a,left,index-1);
}
else {
    quickSort(a,index,length);
}
```

to this

```
quickSort(a,left,index-1);
quickSort(a,index+1,length);
```

Since you need to sort array recursively on every partition of the array!

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort breaks the array into two smaller arrays, on either side of the pivot. This means that each call to quicksort should result in two more calls to quicksort. Your code currently calls quicksort recursively, but only on one half.

```
Quicksort(array)
    pick a pivot
    Arrays left, right
    For each value in array
        If value < pivot
            Append to left array
        Else
            Append to right array
    Quicksort(left)
    Quicksort(right)
    Return join(left, right)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyQuickSort {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //int[] a = { 1, 23, 45, 2, 8, 134, 9, 4, 2000 };
    int a[]={23,44,1,2009,2,88,123,7,999,1040,88};
    quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    System.out.println(a);
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
}

public static void quickSort(int[] a, int p, int r)
{
    if(p<r)
    {
        int q=partition(a,p,r);
        quickSort(a,p,q);
        quickSort(a,q+1,r);
    }
}

private static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r) {

    int x = a[p];
    int i = p-1 ;
    int j = r+1 ;

    while (true) {
        i++;
        while ( i< r && a[i] < x)
            i++;
        j--;
        while (j>p && a[j] > x)
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            swap(a, i, j);
        else
            return j;
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

}

Taken from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/java-implementation-of-quick-sort)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the edited code you can replace it,

```
public void quickSort(int[] a,int left, int length) {

           if(left >= length) return;
            int index = partition(a,left,length);
            if (left < index)
                quickSort(a, left, index);      // left subarray
            if (length > index + 1)
                quickSort(a, index + 1, length);  
        }

        private  int partition(int[] arr,int l, int length) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int pivot = arr[(l + length)/2];
            int left = l - 1;  // index going left to right
            int right = length + 1;   // index going right to left

            while (true) {
                do {
                    left++;
                } while (arr[left] < pivot);
                do {
                    right--;
                } while (arr[right] > pivot); 

                if (left < right){
                int temp = arr[left];
                arr[left] = arr[right];
                arr[right] = temp;
                }
                else
                    return right;   // index of last element in the left subarray
            }    
        }
```

Quicksort is a divide and conquer algorithm. It first divides a large list into two smaller sub-lists and then recursively sort the two sub-lists. If we want to sort an array without any extra space, quicksort is a good option. On average, time complexity is O(n log(n)).

The basic step of sorting an array are as follows:

Select a pivot, normally the middle one
From both ends, swap elements and make all elements on the left less than the pivot and all elements on the right greater than the pivot
Recursively sort left part and right part

Arrays.sort() method in Java use quicksort to sort array of primitives e.g. array of integers or float and uses Mergesort to sot objects e.g. array of String.